# `_Symbol.'for'`: Is that actually valid ES6? Webpack built it from React source

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to take React 0.14 for a spin before I upgrade it in my project. However, with a simple "hello world" prototype, Webpack is throwing an error:

```
ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactElement.js
Module parse failed: /home/dan/Demos/reactiflux/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js!/home/dan/Demos/reactiflux/node_modules/react/lib/ReactElement.js Line 25: Unexpected string
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| // The Symbol used to tag the ReactElement type. If there is no native Symbol
| // nor polyfill, then a plain number is used for performance.
| var REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE = typeof _Symbol === 'function' && _Symbol.'for' && _Symbol.'for'('react.element') || 0xeac7;
| 
| var RESERVED_PROPS = {
 @ ./~/react/lib/ReactMount.js 18:19-44
```

I do have babel-loader configured, and when I downgrade to React 0.13, everything works. What really stands out to me, is `_Symbol.'for'`, in the middle of the error message.

In react/lib/ReactElement.js on line 21 (not 25), that line looks much more correct, with square brackets around the `'for'` key:

```
var REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE = typeof Symbol === 'function' && Symbol['for'] && Symbol['for']('react.element') || 0xeac7;
```

I assume that the code shown in the error message is either in an intermediate state during compilation, or is the final compiled output. Does anyone know what could cause Webpack to produce something that looks so wrong? Has anyone successfully used Webpack, Babel and React ~0.14.1 together yet?

**update**

There is an issue for this: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2377

It's closed, but it looks like it came back for me. This was fixed in 5.8.25, but I have 5.8.29 and I still hit the bug.

Comment: babel/webpack/react 0.14 works perfectly well there are many repos on github using it. Not sure what to suggest as you haven't posted build code or versions used - here's a project I did last week with this setup - https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/

Comment: Yeah, I doubt that this is actually a real bug, which is why I didn't file an issue. But since the project is so small, I'm not really sure what to do to troubleshoot from here. I figured I should check to see if anyone else has made the same mistake, whatever it is. I'll try finding an example of a working build on GH, maybe I can spot an important difference.

Comment: Can you post the code of your "simple hello world prototype"? Especially the build config.

Comment: And to answer your title question: No, that's invalid JS indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not valid code. That was an issue in Babel project, but it has been fixed in the 6.0 version which was released recently.

I was run into this issue too, and now I have checked this with latest version, and it is works fine. Here is my test steps:

```
# install Babel and plugins
npm install babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 babel-plugin-transform-runtime
# install React
npm install react 
# run babel against problem react file
./node_modules/.bin/babel node_modules/react/lib/ReactElement.js --plugins transform-runtime --presets es2015
```

It is provides valid output, so the issue seems to be resolved.

And there is good news for you, [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) for webpack already supports 6 version of Babel. Check out its docs for details

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the problem has something to do with me including babel runtime. My .babelrc was copied from an older project:

```
{
    "optional": "runtime",
    "stage": 0
}
```

In this little hello-world demo, there is nothing that requires bundling the runtime, so I just removed it, after noticing that https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/, which also uses the same build tools, does not need it. That was the only change I needed to make to get this to build.

My webpack config is super simple:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
        filename: "index.min.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "babel"
        }]
    }
};
```

I guess that's what I get for copying a config file from a more complex project into what was supposed to be a simplest possible demo.

I see that there is a [babel-plugin-runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-runtime) as well as a babel-runtime on NPM, but when I tried out BPR for the sake of completeness, Babel complains: `Module build failed: ReferenceError: The plugin "runtime" collides with another of the same name`. Since I don't actually need the runtime, the linked GH repo is a 404, and since this really belongs in the issue trackers after all, this is as far as I am going to take this for now.